# PHP Random Float Number Generator

Tags: php, random

I am new to PHP so sorry if this is messy, I have looked around StackOverflow but I am unable to find anything that fits my need.

I am trying to create a random float number list. But the problem I am having is everytime I run the list it prints out the same number. Can anyone explain why and if there is a way to get different numbers each iteration.

Thank You for any help.

```
<?php
    function frand($min, $max, $decimals = 0) {
        mt_srand(microtime());

        $scale = pow(10, $decimals);

        return mt_rand($min * $scale, $max * $scale) / $scale;
    }

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 45; $x++) {
        echo frand(1, 17, 8) . "<br/>";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mt_srand(microtime());` function only once in your script.

Notice that your code will certainly run quicker than 1 microsecond. Therefore `microtime()` will return same amount of microseconds and `mt_srand` will generate the same seed, which will effect in same results from `mt_rand`.

Try using this code instead:

```
<?php

  function frand($min, $max, $decimals = 0) {
      $scale = pow(10, $decimals);
      return mt_rand($min * $scale, $max * $scale) / $scale;
  }


  mt_srand(microtime());
  for ($x = 1; $x <= 45; $x++) {
      echo frand(1, 17, 8) . "<br/>";
  } 

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call `srand()` or `mt_srand()` only once. They initialize the random number generator. Your code calls it before every call to `mt_rand()` and because the function `frand()` needs much less than a microsecond to complete, you initialize the random number generator with the same value every time.

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) says, there is no need to call `mt_srand()` because the PHP interpreter does it for you.

The only situation when you need to call `mt_rand()` is when you specifically need to always get the same sequence of random numbers; in this case you need to use a controlled value to initialize it, and not the current time.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function frand($min, $max, $decimals = 0) {
$scale = pow(10, $decimals);
return mt_rand($min * $scale, $max * $scale) / $scale;
}

for ($x = 1; $x <= 45; $x++) {
echo frand(1, 17, 8) . "<br/>";
} 
mt_srand(microtime());
```

Comment: @GavW let me know if it is useful for you

Comment: @GavW yea, i'm curious too.

Comment: it works because php runs `mt_srand()` at the start of your script. Your code would work without last line pretty much the same.